# How can I connect to wifi in flutter from the string generated by scanning qr code?

Tags: flutter, dart

After scanning qr code I get a string like this
`WIFI:S:SUPERIOR ;T:WPA;P:12345678;H:false;;`
I have tried splitting that string and getting SSID , password  from that.
Then I have tried using  1. wifi_iot
2. android_flutter_wifi
3. wifi connect
packages to connect to the wifi. But I am unable to do that cause all of the packages return `false` result.

Answer (score 0):

To connect to Wi-Fi in Flutter from a QR code string, you can use the `wifi_iot` package. Here is an example implementation:

First, add the `wifi_iot` package to your `pubspec.yaml` file:

```yaml
dependencies:
  wifi_iot: ^0.5.0
```

Then, in your Dart code, you can split the QR code string to get the SSID and password:

```dart
String qrCode = 'WIFI:S:SUPERIOR;T:WPA;P:12345678;H:false;;';
List<String> qrCodeSplit = qrCode.split(';');
String ssid = qrCodeSplit[0].split(':')[2];
String password = qrCodeSplit[1].split(':')[1];
```

Finally, you can use the `wifi_iot` package to connect to the Wi-Fi network:

```dart
import 'package:wifi_iot/wifi_iot.dart';

await WiFiForIoTPlugin.connect(ssid, password);
```

Note: You may need to request the `android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permission in your AndroidManifest.xml file for this package to work properly.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. After I use This ```await WiFiForIoTPlugin.connect(ssid, password);``` it searches for devices and then says no devices found. also The passoword will be ```String password = qrCodeSplit[2].split(':')[1];```